# How to set default parameter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

My current website works fine when link contains page

`http://localhost/Index?page=1`

But when I do not add any page

`http://localhost/Index`

Website does not load, only returns error. How to set default parameter, so when I do not type any page, it will automatically jump to specific page? I'm using MVC pattern in .NET Framework.

Comment: Is `null` being handled in the controller?

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the error and your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class handling the query string:

```
public class SimplePaginationViewModel
{
    public int Page { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

Then use it in your controller

```
public IActionResult Index(SimplePaginationViewModel viewModel)
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you set query parameter on your action(maybe for pagination or so on...)so you have to  send parameter.
Check your api index and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Route.config in AppStart folder 



public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = 
                         UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
```